# ImageComboBoxEdit selected value not settable

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to add an ImageComboBoxEdit control onto a UserControl within my WinForms application.

```
public ShortCutUserControl()
{
    var imageCollection = new ImageCollection { ImageSize = new Size(48, 48) };
    imageCollection.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"Keyboard\ctrl.ico"));
    imageCollection.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"Keyboard\alt.ico"));
    functionKeyImageComboBoxEdit.Properties.LargeImages = imageCollection;

    ImageComboBoxItem ctrlItem = new ImageComboBoxItem
    {
        Description = "Ctrl",
        ImageIndex = 0
    };
    ImageComboBoxItem altItem = new ImageComboBoxItem
    {
        Description = "Alt",
        ImageIndex = 1
    };
    functionKeyImageComboBoxEdit.Properties.Items.Add(altItem);
    functionKeyImageComboBoxEdit.Properties.Items.Add(ctrlItem);
}
```

When the control is loaded:

[image: User Control]

I can't change the currently either directly through code or in the UI.

```
functionKeyImageComboBoxEdit.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I've tried attaching events to the functionKeyImageComboBoxEdit, but none of these seem to be fired/captured;

```
functionKeyImageComboBoxEdit.SelectedIndexChanged += FunctionKeyImageComboBoxEditOnSelectedIndexChanged;

private void FunctionKeyImageComboBoxEditOnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

What am I missing from my code? I've been looking at the [DevExpress ImageComboBoxEdit Documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsImageComboBoxEdittopic) but can't see any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that you don't set values for ImageComboBoxItems. Do this like:

```
ImageComboBoxItem ctrlItem = new ImageComboBoxItem
{
    Description = "Ctrl",
    ImageIndex = 0,
    Value = "Ctrl"
};
ImageComboBoxItem altItem = new ImageComboBoxItem
{
    Description = "Alt",
    ImageIndex = 1,
    Value = "Alt"
};
```